# datagrid not getting displayed

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I am trying to display the data from sql into a datagrid as follows:

```
 try
    {
        SqlConnection xconn = new SqlConnection();
        xconn.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=servername; Trusted_Connection=yes; Database=master";
        xconn.Open();
        string s = "select * from tablename where name=@name";
        SqlCommand ycmd = new SqlCommand(s, xconn);

        ycmd.Parameters.Add("@name", dropdownlistname.SelectedValue);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(ycmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        gridview.DataSource = dt;
        gridview.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception e2)
    {
        lblresult.Text = e2.Message + "<br />" + e2.StackTrace  ; 
    }
```

I do not get any exception . However , the grid is not displayed.

Comment: Does `da` have any values in it after you execute the `Fill()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  like this....

you can change this depends on your requirement ....

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Product.ID=@PROD_ID";
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PROD_ID", 100));

// Execute the SQL Server command...
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
DataTable tblProducts = new DataTable();
tblProducts.Load(reader);

foreach (DataRow rowProduct in tblProducts.Rows)
{
    // Use the data...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are defining a parameter `@name` to your sql statement but you are never feeding any value since the version of `SqlCommand.Parameters.Add` that takes 2 parameters is the one that receives **parameterName** and **SqlDbType**

I am surprised you are not getting exceptions. Perhaps your `dropdownlistname.SelectedValue` matches one of the enumeration values for **SqlDbType** and that's why?

You should be doing:

```
ycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", dropdownlistname.SelectedValue);
```